# Debugging PHP-based MVC controller interactively

Tags: php, model-view-controller, debugging, indefero

I'm trying to get indefero working on a webhost I'm running, and the /login URL simply appears to be redirecting back to the main controller.  I assume I have a setup issue, and rather than bother the developers, I figure I can blunder through and figure it out.  (I'm somewhat familiar with PHP).  What I'm not familiar with, is if there's

A) a comparable option to **/bin/sh -x** which shows line-by-line results of processing 
 B) an easy way to send URL parameters to the script without modifying it

It would be nice to be able to do **php5 index.php url=/login** to test.  Short of that, I'll have to start hacking the old-fashioned way.  :-)  Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a to have a PHP extension such as [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org) setup on your server to do remote debugging of the manner you describe, and have an application or IDE that supports it. If you have the ability to install this or have it available then you can pick an IDE, but if you're on shared hosting chances are you are out of luck.